# Parsing an NSDictionary in one operation ( remove loop).

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Could you please guide me on how not to use a for loop in this example? I want to execute it one operation if possible:

```
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {                  
    test = [status objectForKey:@"USER_ID"];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in a single operation? Could you elaborate.

Comment: i not want  use for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)

Comment: i want use only on time NSDictionary *status in statuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];


if ([statuses count]>0) {

        test=[[statuses objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"USER_ID"];      

}
```

Comment: welcome buddy.for instant help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Comment: This will throw an exception if the parser returned an empty array. It would be safer to use [statuses lastObject] instead of objectAtIndex:

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the NSArray has only one element (or that the NSDictionary you want is always the first, or at some other fixed position), use `[statuses objectAtIndex:0]` (or whatever index) to fetch the `status` element.

Comment: if i  use  statuses objectAtIndex:0] the result is  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: That should only happen if statuses is empty (and your original code would leave test nil).  If that's possible you need to throw a if(statuses.count > 0) condition around the whole sequence.